# Batch delete text box in PDF

Tags: pdf

How can I batch delete multiple text boxes in a PDF?

The scenario is that I have a number of PDF documents with a text box at the top and bottom of each page which I want to delete. I can do this manually using software such as Master PDF Editor but the document has over 500 pages and I have several documents to process. I'm fairly sure these are text boxes and not header/footers.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Easy,

use iText7 in combination with pdfSweep.
iText is a PDF toolkit that enables you to create, edit and extract information from PDF documents.

pdfSweep (as the name implies) provides redaction capabilities for iText.
You can redact content from a specific page, or range of pages, given a rectangle (and soon regular expression).

pdfSweep will then remove all the content that falls within the given rectangle.

You can also simply create redaction annotations, and then have them batch-removed by Adobe Reader. iText also supports creating redaction annotations.

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(
fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) {
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(stream);
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(
    pdfReader, new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))) {
    int page = 1;
    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect =
        new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(500, 50, 200, 300);
    PdfAnnotation annotation = new PdfAnnotation(stamper.Writer, rect);
    annotation.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, new PdfName("Redact"));
    annotation.Title = "My Author";
    annotation.Put(new PdfName("Subj"), new PdfName("Redact"));
    float[] fillColor = { 0, 0, 0 };
    annotation.Put(new PdfName("IC"), new PdfArray(fillColor));
    float[] fillColorRed = { 1, 0, 0 };
    annotation.Put(new PdfName("OC"), new PdfArray(fillColorRed));
    stamper.AddAnnotation(annotation, page);
}
```

}

iText and pdfSweep are available in java or C#.

There's a fairly comprehensive example on the iText website on how to generate redaction annotations:
http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-create-and-apply-redactions

Comment: Thanks Joris, but I was hoping for a slightly simpler solution. Perhaps using red gui based PDF editor tool?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, as soon as you want to do any kind of content processing (and especially in batch) it will quickly escalate to having to do some code.

Comment: Makes sense. So, are iText7 and pdfSweep free? Do I just install them, take your example, compile and run it? Obviously tweaking it to my needs

Comment: Both are open source and AGPL licensed. That means that you are allowed to use them for free in non-commercial settings. And if you open source your code, you are allowed to use them for free in a commercial setting as well. If you  don't want to (or can not) open source your code, and you wish to use them commercially, you'll need to obtain a license agreement.

Comment: Mine would be non-commercial use, so no problems there

Answer (score -1):

Not really hard to do in Adobe Acrobat and no third party software needed. Open the Comments drop down menu on the right-hand side of the Acrobat window. There you can see a list with all the text boxes in the document. Now select all the text boxes that you want to delete using the Control or Shift key + the left mouse button for selecting them, whichever suits your needs best. If you want to delete them all, left-click the first item in the list, then scroll down the list to the bottom, hold the Shift key and left-click the item at the bottom. Then finally use the mouse's right button and choose delete. Now they're gone.